TailwindCSS not working with Vite + React - style element inside project?
I have configuration like this. I would try to pick background from div element with default parameter from tailwind configuration "bg-lime-400" and doesn't work.
vite.config.js
import {defineConfig, loadEnv} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
    const env = loadEnv(mode,  process.cwd(), '')
    return{
        define: {
           'import.meta.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(env.API_URL)
        },
        plugins: [react()],
        css: {
            postcss: {
                plugins: [tailwindcss()],
            },
        },
    }
})

postcss.config.js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}

tailwind.config.js
export default {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false
  },
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      general: ['"General Sans"', 'sans-serif']
    },
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: [],
}

main.tsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.scss'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

App.tsx
import './App.scss'

function App() {

  return (
    <>
        <div className="bg-lime-400">ddddd</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

index.scss
@tailwind base;
@layer base {
  html {
    @apply font-general
  }
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Project structure
image
Image from website image
Why cannot style element? Anybody answers? Please.....

bg-event-60 would not evaluate to a class with your Tailwind configuration.
If you intend for it to apply background-color, you'd need to modify your Tailwind configuration to add the value as a colors.event.60:
export default {
  // …
  theme: {
    // …
    extend: {
      colors: {
        event: {
          '60': 'some color value',

Or colors.event-60:
export default {
  // …
  theme: {
    // …
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'event-60': 'some color value',

Or backgroundColor.event.60:
export default {
  // …
  theme: {
    // …
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        event: {
          '60': 'some color value',

Or backgroundColor.event-60:
export default {
  // …
  theme: {
    // …
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        'event-60': 'some color value',

Otherwise, if you intended for the class name to apply backgroundImage, you'd need to modify your Tailwind configuration to add the value as a backgroundImage.event-60:
export default {
  // …
  theme: {
    // …
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'event-60': 'some color value',


You seem to have an incorrect file glob in the content array of your Tailwind configuration:
export default {
  // …
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}"],

At the moment, this would expand to:
./index.html
./src/**/*.js
./src/**/*. ts
./src/**/*. jsx
./src/**/*. tsx

Notice the spaces after the dot (.) for the ts, jsx and tsx candidates. Consider removing the spaces like:
content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],

So that these would expand to:
./index.html
./src/**/*.js
./src/**/*.ts
./src/**/*.jsx
./src/**/*.tsx

Thus, Tailwind would scan your src/App.tsx file and properly create CSS rules for matching class name candidates found in this src/App.tsx file.

sorry man i use default value from tailwind configuration like bg-lime-400 and steal doesnt work. However when i use property custom value like event-60 steal not working......

Try removing the css configuration object from vite.config.js. If you want to use a custom value for bg-event-60, you'd need to also modify your Tailwind configuration as outlined in my answer. Updated answer with a different misconfiguration I spotted.

Great answer for spaces.... Thank you for answer! I approach you!
